# Does boiling meatball remove some flavor

Tags: boiling, meatballs

I want to cook some meatballs by boiling them in plain water.  Does this remove flavor from the meatballs?

I have a instantpot pressure cooker and I thought it would be way easier than baking for example.

Comment: Yes, probably, why are you wanting to do that ?

Comment: "remove flavor" in comparison to what, raw meat?

Comment: Pretty standard is to “cook” them in tomato sauce. Is there a reason you want to avoid that?

Comment: Could you include your recipe and typical cooking method? (For example, some meatballs are baked, some are pan-fried, some are boiled in sauce...) It's tough to know how much flavor you may lose without knowing how they're typically cooked :)

Comment: @Erica I usually stew them inside tomato sauce and eat it with pasta

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly poach meatballs.  I wouldn't boil them, as the rolling action could tear them apart. It is more common to poach in a sauce, however water can certainly be used. You will lose some flavor (taste the water afterward, you will see), however, it wouldn't be a reason to avoid the technique if you have a purpose for it.  Lots of things are poached and still have flavor.

Answer (score 2):

they definitely would lose some flavour depending on the time you are going to boil them.

rather just steam them that way you wouldn't loose much of the flavours if you have to go with this method.

*What I do is I just sauté them in frying pan for few minutes so they are little browned from outside it enhances their flavour by 10 folds.*